# SSH proxy to establish HTTPS connection with git server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, git

I am working on a machine that does not have direct access to the internet, but other nodes on the domain do.  This means that I can ssh to another machine to sync my git repo, but I cannot do it from the machine itself.

```
> git clone https://git.example.com/git/myproj.git ~
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.example.com/git/myproj.git'

> ssh machine2
> git clone https://git.example.com/git/myproj.git ~
successfully cloned into '~/myproj'
```

I would like to be able to use `machine2` as a proxy to connect to the git server.  Unfortunately, `machine2` is not configured as an http proxy, and the git server is not configured to use the `git://` or `ssh://` protocols.   Is there a way that I can use `machine2` as a proxy to establish an https connection with `git.example.com`?  Note that I do not have sudo privileges on `machine2`.

### Update:

A complicating factor appears to be the fact that I am using a private key to authenticate with the HTTPS server.  In my `~/.gitconfig` I have the following lines

```
[http]
    sslkey = /home/nispio/.ssl/example.key.pem
    sslkey = /home/nispio/.ssl/example.crt.pem
    sslcainfo = /home/nispio/.ssl/example-ca.crt.pem
```

All of this is configured properly, as evidenced by the fact that I can successfully clone the repo from `machine2` using these credentials.  Attempting to use a simple socks server as [proposed by @IporSircer](https://superuser.com/a/1128582/251386) however, does not seem to forward my credentials properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh socks server:

```
ssh -D 1080 machine2

git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'
git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'
git clone https://git.example.com/git/myproj.git ~
```

Comment: `fatal: unable to access ... : Proxy CONNECT aborted`  Is there a good way  to verify the socks server independent of git?

Comment: After playing with a toy example, I realized that the problem only exists when using key authentication over SSL.  I will update the question.

Comment: `Proxy CONNECT aborted` This way is not working